# Connection management WPA2 hotspot in Win 8 CP

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview

I have a question featuring the by microsoft proudly presented connection manager.

I only just discovered that all possibilities to manage saved internet connections have been removed, and the connection manager added newly in windows 8 should provide this functionality. Now, I ran into the following problem:

**Case**
I wanted to connect to my schools network which is an eduroam hotspot encrypted using WPA2-Enterprise.

**Problem**
The network was detected automatically, but connecting failed. It did detect the network being a hotspot and asked for my credentials. I never had touched any settings yet, so I figured I'd try setting the encryption type to WPA2-Enterprise. That's where the trouble started: I couldn't for the life of me find a way to edit the connection.

**Own attempts**
First, I tried the connection manager itself (the screen that comes out in the right) and right clicked the connection to edit it. That didn't work (right clicking didn't do anything at all). Later, I found out that I can right-click networks I am already connected to, but not ones I can't connect with.

Of course, I scoured the Network and Sharing center, and there the option to manage existing networks is simply gone from the menu, leaving a blank line between the options. Also couldn't find another way to manage the connections.

I used the troubleshooter, but it wouldn't allow me to manually edit settings.

Then, I tried adding a network manually, but I couldn't add a network with the ID 'eduroam' because it aleady exists. Can't delete it, because I can't right click it or find another way.

Lastly, the help document stated that I should go to connection manager, then right click the connection and click delete, which, as I stated, doesn't work for me. Also, I know that when I leave the building, the connection won't be listed anymore so I can only edit it when it is in range, even though it is a stored connection..

Any help is very welcome!
Regards

Comment: You do it the same way you would do it in Windows 7.

Comment: Which is
Control panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing center -> manage connections. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else looking for this, this is the only answer I have found:

Enter this line into the run window (meta + R):

```
explorer.exe shell:::{1fa9085f-25a2-489b-85d4-86326eedcd87}
```

Or enter this line into your explorer:

```
shell:::{1fa9085f-25a2-489b-85d4-86326eedcd87}
```

For easy access, you can make a shortcut anywhere and enter the first line into location. It will take you to the 'classic' connection management screen.